# Project files hidden in Visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I clone the project from Tfs and try to run in visual studio. But it showing hidden files. But in computer folder it showing perfectly. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.[image]

Answer (score 19):

There is a "Show all files" button in the Solution Explorer. Make sure that is selected.

[image]

Comment: Ya I selected before. But it doesn't make change.

Comment: So which files are you missing exactly? Like .*proj files?

Comment: All files(Authentication, bin, Chat etc.) are showing hidden . But if I check my folders everything is there.

Comment: Ah, right, you must right click on those files and select "Include in Project". Then Check-in and they will be included in your commit and then any subsequent pull downs

Comment: Thank you I added those project Manually by including into project. But what is the reson they are invisible and also in the errror list saying "run nuget package restore to generate this file ". but I tried everything they are already restored and it said "Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies."

Answer (score 7):

For Visual Studio for Mac, version 8.7.4, you can do this; right click on the project file, then:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

select hidden files and folders right click and choose include in project it works perfectly

Answer (score -2):

There is no question formulated, just a comment about the hidden files. But if you have files missing then use button to show hidden files, the "Show All file", as hmiedema9 instructed. If you find the files among the hidden files, and you want to include them in your project versioning control, use the "Include in Project" tip from @hmiedema9. If your project is missing these files you have to include them in the project and rebuild the solution, at lesast. Commit your job after all. Good luck.