# Opening a C# project without .sln / .csproj file

Tags: c#

I'm confronted with a (seemingly) C# project.
However, there is no .sln or .csproj file.

However, I see a CMakeList.txt. I have added its contents at the end of this question.

How could I open this project in VS 2019? 
Or is there something missing in order to open the project?
Before asking the producer and perhaps stand like a complete newbie, I wanted to make sure there is nothing I have forgotten.

Here is a list of the files that I have:

[image]
Contents of CMakeList.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT( IrisbondAPITestCS LANGUAGES CSharp)

INCLUDE( CSharpUtilities )


SET( PROGRAM_SRC 
    App.config
    Program.cs
    Test.cs
    Test.Designer.cs
    Test.resx
    IrisbondDuo.cs
    WinAPI.cs
    MouseInput.cs
    NativeMethods.cs
)

SET( PROPERTIES_SRC 
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROGRAM_SRC} ${PROPERTIES_SRC} )

CSHARP_SET_WINDOWS_FORMS_PROPERTIES(
    Test.cs
    Test.Designer.cs
    Test.resx
)

CSHARP_SET_WINDOWS_FORMS_PROPERTIES( ${PROPERTIES_SRC} )


# set_property(SOURCE App.xaml PROPERTY VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")

SET_PROPERTY( TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.5.1")
SET_PROPERTY( TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)

SET_PROPERTY( TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
    "System.Deployment"
    "System.Drawing"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
    "System.Xml"
    "System.Xml.Linq"
)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} IrisbondAPI)
```

Edit:
This is what my VS2019 Community looks like:

[image]

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2019#create-a-project-from-existing-code-files) might be what you're searching for

Comment: @Artur Thank you, but I don't see this option / wizard in my VS2019. Do you?

Comment: I do have the `File > New > Project From Existing Code`. I have VS2019 Professional, but nothing in the linked article talks about this being a version specific feature.

Comment: Visually, I have the same menu as in [this article](https://dailydotnettips.com/create-a-project-from-existing-code-files-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a new project and move your files in the new project's folder. After unloading and reloading, everything *should* be fine. You would have to add the files to the `.csproj` manually though (through the interface).

Comment: @Artur Thank you. My community VS2019 looks totally different. I have added a screenshot to my post. While it's German, I guess the icons still tell everything, and you can see that my "New" section does not expand like yours, but there is only "New..." (which opens up a new window with a wizard and no "Project From Existing Code").

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about creating a new project. However I'm not experienced enough yet to create the csproj file.

Comment: Weird (about the screenshot)! For the .csproj, I meant create a solution with the VS interface (a new project), then shut it down, move your files into the newly created solution folder and re-open the solution. Your .cs files will be missing, so just add them [like so[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633866/project-files-hidden-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @Artur Thank you very much! Your solution ("Alternatively, you could create a new project...") perfectly did it for me. If you want to, you can post this comment as a answer so that I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Certainly, glad I could help. the posted answer goes a bit more in depth, and if it's not what you actually ended up doing, please comment to specify the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in solution to this issue is explained in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2019#create-a-project-from-existing-code-files). It uses the `Create Project from Existing Code Files wizard`, which you can get to by going to `File > New > Project From Existing Code`.

However, if for some reason the built in solution does not work for you (OP for example, did not have that option. The wizzard might not be available on the community version of VS2019), you can take one of these routes:

If your `properties` folder is not important:

1. Create a new project.
2. Move your files in the new project's folder. (excluding the properties folder)
3. You will have to add the code files to the `.csproj` manually. Either by modifying it directly (which is not always fun), or simply showing all hidden files like so and including them into the solution `right click on item > Include In Project`.
4. That's it, things should work.
   5.

If your `properties` folder is important:

1. Create a new project.
2. Unload the project `right click ont he project > Unload project`
3. Move your files in the new project's folder. Replace the conflicts in the `properties` folder.
4. You will have to add the code files to the `.csproj` manually. Either by modifying it directly (which is not always fun), or simply showing all hidden files like so and including them into the solution `right click on item > Include In Project`.
   5.That's it, things should work.

---

Edit: FYI (didn't know myself), did some research on the `make` file in your folder, it's something used in the `CLion` IDE, so that is why there was no VS solution in there to begin with.

Comment: In the latest version of VS2019 community, it's "File->CMake..."